# ExtJs 4 chart: disable/enable resizing feature

Tags: extjs, charts, resize

I am using Extjs 4.0 and would like to have a button to disable and enable resizing feature of extjs pie chart. 
Ext.chart.Chart has resizable attribute in configs but no relevant method exists for changing it, like setResizable(true/false).

I tried to change the property like this:
chart.resizable = false;

But it didn't work.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

```
chart.resizer.resizeTracker.disable(); //Disables resizer
chart.resizer.resizeTracker.enable(); //Enables resizer
```